# How to know if a channelDisconnected comes from the client or server in a Netty client

Tags: netty

We're having a couple of Netty clients with handlers which are sharable and doesn't containt any mutable state. The handler is added to a `StaticChannelPipline`. I would like to know if there's a way to know if a `channelDisconnected` is due to the server closing the connection or not to be able to notify that case by invoking a callback that the client has specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `SimpleChannelDownstreamHandler.closeRequested()` to get notified when your application calls `Channel.close()`.

However, even if you called `Channel.close()`, there is always a race condition where a remote peer attempted to close the connection at the same time.  Therefore, it's not a good idea to determine your application's behavior depending 'which side` closed the connection.

Alternatively, you could define a `good-bye` message in your protocol and require a client to send the good-bye message before disconnecting.  Then you know better if the client terminated its connection as it intended or not.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to know that to be able to invoke a client listener callback when the server closed the connection. I'll settle with having a isConnected() method that the user of the client can use instead.